# How to convert JAVA Object to JSON Efficiently..?

Tags: java, json, mule, transformer-model

I am using **Mule**. I have a JAVA Object that is populated from my internal Class..It is actually a `HashMap<String,Object>`. `Object` can be anything..another `HashMap`, OR `List` etc ..Now i have to convert it into `JSON` (and removing all those keys that have value as NULL)..

When i use a given Mule Transformer , `ObjectToJSON`, it is converting into appropriate JSON..but not able to remove NULL value..And i could not find any properties to set in **Custom-transformer** that will remove NULL values..!!

---

So then, i wrote a **custom transformer**, that uses the `net.sf.json-lib` library and i am able to remove NULL values.

But in one of my JAVA Object , i have a `HashMap<Integer,String>` and since in JSON Object , Integer cannot be keys, `net.sf.json` library is giving an Exception :

```
Exception stack is:
1. JSON keys must be strings. (java.lang.ClassCastException)
  net.sf.json.JSONObject:1120 (null)
2. java.lang.ClassCastException: JSON keys must be strings. (net.sf.json.JSONException)
  net.sf.json.JSONObject:1160 (null)
3. java.lang.ClassCastException: JSON keys must be strings. (net.sf.json.JSONException). Message payload is of type: HashMap (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerMessagingException)
```

and so it is unable to convert it into JSON..

---

So what is most viable option..??

Comment: If JSON doesn't allow keys to be a number, can start your keys with an `_` e.g. ` { _1: Hello, _9: World } `

Comment: No..i have already made my JAVA code..and i cannot make changes in it..Secondly, i have to given Integer to my front end APP.. (although it can be an Integer String like "1") ..!!..please suggest what to do..!!

Answer (score 8):

I would recommend you to try [gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) it worked like a magic for me.

Collections Examples

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Collection<Integer> ints = Lists.immutableList(1,2,3,4,5);
```

(Serialization)

```
String json = gson.toJson(ints); ==> json is [1,2,3,4,5]
```

(Deserialization)

```
Type collectionType = new TypeToken<Collection<Integer>>(){}.getType();
Collection<Integer> ints2 = gson.fromJson(json, collectionType);
```

ints2 is same as ints

Here is an example of how to write a custom serializer for JodaTime DateTime class.

```
private class DateTimeSerializer implements JsonSerializer<DateTime> {
  public JsonElement serialize(DateTime src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext  context) {
    return new JsonPrimitive(src.toString());
  }
}
```

Comment: i have looked at it and i found two issues...First of all, it **does not covert SubObjects to JSON** And secondly, **i was not able to Parse Datetime** ..The **setDateFormat** property does not work in gson..it is reported bug in gson library..!!

Comment: @RamandeepSingh, what is 'SubObject'? The Date issue was fixed in the recent verison and anyway you can write your own de/serializer - see my edit.

Comment: **subObjects** : I have `HashMap<String,Object>` ..Now `Object` can be another `HashMap<String,Object>` which will considered as **SubObject**..!!

Comment: so why to use raw types in the first place? and BTW you can write your own de/serializer which checks the type and treats the complex type properly.

Comment: you are not understanding..I have made a generic code..that can give either `List` OR `HashMap` which i put in my final `HashMap`..So thats y i have used raw types..!!

Comment: ok, so, your code fails to interpret value as type HashMap<String, Object> because Gson invokes list.getClass() to get its class information, but this method returns a raw class, HashMap<String,Object>().class. This means that Gson has no way of knowing that this is an object of type HashMap<String,Object>, and not just plain HashMap. You can solve this problem by specifying the correct parameterized type for your generic type. You can do this by using the TypeToken class.

Comment: it is not about one level nesting..it is about multi-level nesting..!!..it can be `HashMap<String,HashMap<String,List<HashMap<String,Object>>>` ..so no use of that..!!

Comment: Well, I fail to imagine the problem that justifies such complex hierarchy. Maybe you can elaborate on what are you trying to do? Anyway I would suggest you to consider redesign :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at Gson?

http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Null-Object-Support

Comment: look my comment for other answer suggesting **gson** ..!!

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt

> An object structure is represented as a pair of curly brackets surrounding zero or more name/value pairs (or members). A name is a string.

I would suggest to modify your initial Java structure to use String as key type.

However with Jackson library you can create fancier solutions:

1. Use a custom deserializer [Deserializing non-string map keys with Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246748/deserializing-non-string-map-keys-with-jackson)
2. Use a Tree Model instead of your own Java POJO http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes